# JavaScript Number Issues

Tags: javascript, html

I was given this code in a previously asked question:

```js
var num = 0

function addNumber() {

  num = num += 1

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = num;


}

function subtractFive() {


  num = num -= 5

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = num;

}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" onclick="addNumber()" />

<button onclick="subtractFive()">Subract 5 from the number.</button>

<p id="output"></p>
```

and I am wondering if I can stylize the number. I also want to know if it is possible to prevent the number from going into the negative when it is 4 or below.

Comment: Yes, you can do both of those things.  Apply CSS to the element whose innerHTML will receive the number.  In your function, check whether the number to be subtracted is greater than the minuend.  When you've coded that, if you have problems, ask us.

Comment: Note you can just use `num += 1` (or `++num`) instead of `num = num += 1`. And `num -= 5` instead of `num = num -= 5`.

Comment: To test if the number is lower/higher/equal you want to use an [if-statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) for example `if (num < 0) num = 0` for "if num is less than zero, then set num to zero"

Comment: @Oriol You are right that one CAN do that. One could also do `num -= num < 5 ? num : 5` but for someone who just started to learn the language it isn't important right now. Let them learn the basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to prevent negative number use this

```
function subtractFive() {

if (num > 4 ) {
num = num -= 5

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = num; }

}
```

to stylize number for example make them red use this

```
<p  style="color:red" id="output"></p>
```

for more text style parameters visit
[Css text](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp)